# Adding horizontal scrolling to "storyboard made" textView not working

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll, uitextview

i've tried all the previous answer to the same question but i can't figure it out!
i have a textView created in the storyboard and i would like to add an horizontal scrolling.
All the tutorials used a programmatically created textView but i would like to use the one i've already done.

i tried to create

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *myScrollView;
```

and connect to my textView, while in the viewDidLoad i wrote

```
myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myTextView.frame.size.width + 50, 500);
```

but this was clearly a dumb way :)
any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Is the textView *in* the scroll view?

Comment: no, i just created a textView in the storyboard, how can i create it in a scroll view?